# Filling area for a manipulate Plot_Can anyone advise? Thank you!

Tags: plotting

```
Manipulate[ 
  Plot[
    N[(1/ 2 (ah^2/(ah - al)^2 - Sqrt[( ah^4 - 4 ah^2 al^2 + 8 ah al^3 - 4 al^4)/(ah - al)^4]))
    ]
  , {ah, 10, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {10, 0}, PlotRange -> Full
  ]
, {al, 5, 9.999}
]
```

[image]

Hi,

Would anyone advise how to full the area under and above this downward slope function? I tried but it does not seem to work.

Any help will be truly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try something like `Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, FillingStyle -> {Green, Blue}`

Comment: Hi Nasser, thank you very much for your reply, which has been greatly helpful!!!!!